# adb pull -> device not found

Tags: android, shell, adb, root

I have a rooted phone and running adb in root mode.

I used adb shell to successfully access the phone.

I can browse directorys, even those who require root.

When i try to use:

```
adb pull /data/data/my.app.path/databases/mydatabase.db /home/admin/Desktop/
```

I get the following error:

```
error: device not found
```

The adb shell stays connected and i can go on browsing the sdcard.

Can anyone tell me where this error comes from and how i can fix it to pull the file?

Comment: are you within shell ?

Comment: dont stay within shell to pull

Comment: That was a stupid one! Yes i was. Please create an Answer Arju and i will accept it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Stay out of shell during `adb pull`.

Answer (score 10):

Seems that nobody provided an explanation yet.

The error has no relation to adb running as root. Running `adb pull` from inside a shell in Android expects an Android device (running adb server) connected to primary Android device as slave, which of course doesn't exist, and so comes the error.

However, you can run that command successfully from inside an Android, if you connect your primary Android device via OTG to another device and that one starts charging (becomes a slave). In that way, you can in fact do `adb shell` from inside your primary Android.

Otherwise, you can run ADB on your device or the other device in TCP mode and do `adb connect <IP:PORT>` from inside the primary device's shell to connect to localhost or the other device's shell.

Even then, your command `adb pull /data/data/my.app.path/databases/mydatabase.db /home/admin/Desktop/` is bound to fail because there is no `/home` directory concept in Android and so, the destination simply doesn't exist in Android.

Though you already know, you've to come back to your PC's shell so that your primary device can be treated as a slave or a server, and your command would run successfully (readers: root is required for this command to work).

Comment: This is the perfect way to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
adb wait-for-device pull /data/data/my.app.path/databases/mydatabase.db 
    /home/admin/Desktop/
```

This way `adb` will wait for your device to be connected. It may help but I am not sure.

Comment: nice to know wait-for-device command, unfortunally it waits until timeout.

Answer (score 0):

don't use the shell

```
cd to platform-tools folder
use the ad pull source_folder_in _android_device distaniation_in_mac
```

example

```
cd /Users/rRasoul/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools  
adb pull /data/data/com.test.app.debug/files /Users/Rasoul/Desktop/folder1
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use 'adb shell pull', instead:

```
adb pull <path>
```